# Create rectangles in a grid with mousemove event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I'm trying to do a simple game with js but I have some problems.

What I want to do is with the mousemove event in a canvas create a grid of rectangles while mouse move with random colors.

My code:

JS:

```js
var NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS = 4;
var NUM_RECTANGLES_DOWN = 10;


function random_color() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

    return {
        "r" : r,
        "g" : g,
        "b" : b
    };
}

window.onload = () => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var rect_x = canvas.width / NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS;
    var rect_y = canvas.height / NUM_RECTANGLES_DOWN;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
        var color = random_color();

        var layer_x = event.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var layer_y = event.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS; i++) {
            if (x >= layer_x) {
                break;
            }

            x += rect_x;
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color.r + ", " + color.g + ", " + color.b + ")"
        ctx.rect(x, y, rect_x, rect_y);
        ctx.fill();
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
    #canvas {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The problem is:
When i move the mouse over the canvar the rectangle is not creating where the mouse is.

See yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/d0petzjm/

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close there's just a couple things that are tripping you up.

```
canvas.width
```

is not what you think it is, if you open up the dev console your canvas.width is set to 300 rather than the 400 you're expecting - you need to add:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 500;
```

Also, your logic for incrementing x should look something like:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS; i++) {
        if (x + rect_x  < layer_x) {
            x += rect_x;
        }
    }
```

Here's a working example, there's still possible improvement but this should get you in the right direction!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<style>
    #canvas {
        width: 400px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>

<script>

var NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS = 4;
var NUM_RECTANGLES_DOWN = 10;


function random_color() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

    return {
        "r" : r,
        "g" : g,
        "b" : b
    };
}

window.onload = () => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 500;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var rect_x = canvas.clientWidth / NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS;
    var rect_y = canvas.clientHeight / NUM_RECTANGLES_DOWN;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
        var color = random_color();
        var layer_x = event.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var layer_y = event.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < NUM_RECTANGLES_ACROSS; i++) {
            if (x + rect_x  < layer_x) {
                x += rect_x;
            }
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color.r + ", " + color.g + ", " + color.b + ")"
        ctx.rect(x, y, rect_x, rect_y);
        ctx.fill();
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are a genius